# Calendar highlight current date automatically

Tags: javascript, html, css, calendar, highlight

I'm making a calendar with HTML, CSS and JavaScript. I want it to highlight current date automatically. Here is my code:

```js
hday();

function hday() {
    var d = new Date().getDate();
    document.getElementById(d).classList.add('today'); 
}
```

```css
.today { 
    background: red; 
}
```

```html
<ul class="days">
    <li id="01">1</li>
    <li id="02">2</li>
    <li id="03">3</li>
    <li id="04">4</li>
    <li id="05">5</li>
    <li id="06">6</li>
    <li id="07">7</li>
    <li id="08">8</li>
    <li id="09">9</li>
    <li id="10">10</li>
    <li id="11">11</li>
    <li id="12">12</li>
    <li id="13">13</li>
    <li id="14">14</li>
    <li id="15">15</li>
    <li id="16">16</li>
    <li id="17">17</li>
    <li id="18">18</li>
    <li id="19">19</li>
    <li id="20">20</li>
    <li id="21">21</li>
    <li id="22">22</li>
    <li id="23">23</li>
    <li id="24">24</li>
    <li id="25">25</li>
    <li id="26">26</li>
    <li id="27">27</li>
    <li id="28">28</li>
    <li id="29">29</li>
    <li id="30">30</li>
    <li id="31">31</li>
  </ul>
```

However, the current date is not highlighted. From chrome developer tools, I found that "background : red" didn't apply to the date today. How to make it work?

I just started HTML and CSS, so sorry for basic Questions.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with order of operations. You need to call the method `hday()` ***after*** you define it.

You have:

```
hday();

function hday() {
    var d = new Date().getDate();
    document.getElementById(d).classList.add('today'); 
}
```

You need:

```js
function hday() {
    var d = new Date().getDate();
    document.getElementById(d).classList.add('today'); 
}

hday();
```

```css
.today { 
background: red; 
}
```

```html
<ul class="days">
    <li id="01">1</li>
    <li id="02">2</li>
    <li id="03">3</li>
    <li id="04">4</li>
    <li id="05">5</li>
    <li id="06">6</li>
    <li id="07">7</li>
    <li id="08">8</li>
    <li id="09">9</li>
    <li id="10">10</li>
    <li id="11">11</li>
    <li id="12">12</li>
    <li id="13">13</li>
    <li id="14">14</li>
    <li id="15">15</li>
    <li id="16">16</li>
    <li id="17">17</li>
    <li id="18">18</li>
    <li id="19">19</li>
    <li id="20">20</li>
    <li id="21">21</li>
    <li id="22">22</li>
    <li id="23">23</li>
    <li id="24">24</li>
    <li id="25">25</li>
    <li id="26">26</li>
    <li id="27">27</li>
    <li id="28">28</li>
    <li id="29">29</li>
    <li id="30">30</li>
    <li id="31">31</li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Sorry for this bad question. The problem is not shown in the code that I provided. The JS file run before the html element is created. This is a stupid mistake made by me. Sorry again, but still thanks for your generous answer.